# Intermediate table not updated when saving an entity

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have a set of entities user and conference. I have implemented a method in which I assign users to a conference and save it. However, when I save the conferencce the intermediate table attendance_table is not updated.

My database erd diagram example:

[image: My image]

My entities:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user_table", schema = "public")
 public class User {
@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long user_id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "confirmed")
private boolean confirmed;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "attendance_table",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "conference_id", referencedColumnName = "conference_id",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Collection<Conference> conferences = new HashSet<>();




 @Entity
 @Table(name = "conference_table", schema = "public")
 public class Conference {

@Id
@Column(name = "conference_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long conference_id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User creator ;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "startConference")
private Date startConference;

@Column(name = "endConference")
private Date endConference;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "conferences", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<User> students;
```

Any ideas? If you need any extra info I can update the question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This was a interesting fix. I was messing around with the user and conference classes and found a solution.

I had to swap the implementations of @ManyToMany of both classes for it to work.

My User class now looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table", schema = "public")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long user_id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "confirmed")
private boolean confirmed;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_role_table",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
private Collection<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Conference> conferences;
```

And my conference class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conference_table", schema = "public")
public class Conference {

@Id
@Column(name = "conference_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long conference_id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User creator ;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "startConference")
private Date startConference;

@Column(name = "endConference")
private Date endConference;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "attendance_table",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "conference_id", referencedColumnName = "conference_id",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                        nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Collection<User> students = new HashSet<>();
```

Still not exactly sure why it works like this and not the other way around. If anyone knows please explain!